# JENKINS - org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsCompilationErrorsException: startup failed - unable to resolve

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am using the `Jenkins 2.387.1`. I am getting the below error. However, I have tried to install this plugin `workflow-cps-global-lib-plugin`, but it did not work. The jobs are running fine in the Jenkins version `2.289.3` without the plugin.
Is there any issue or any other plugin required for the Jenkins `2.387.1`?

Below are the jenkins logs:

```
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] echo
autoDeploy = true
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Also:   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.ErrorAction$ErrorId: 91a17692-d7fa-4c51-aac6-cd76bdfc646a
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/QWER - ASDFG/jobs/dfdfdf-xyz-service/branches/master/builds/5/libs/e78359ceddbfb472d95ded9ca3b77e3248d2f02ed8c0c0e3e528/vars/buildDeployPipeline.groovy: 70: Invalid parameter "hccEnv", did you mean "ssh"? @ line 70, column 42.
                kubernetesDeploy(hccEnv: 'd
                                 ^
```

Thanks

Pritish

Comment: You don't need `workflow-cps-global-lib-plugin`, your problem is most likely with the unexpected revision of your shared library. How do you load the library in your pipeline? And what's the `kubernetesDeploy` method signature?

Answer (score 0):

The exception message in the output is: **Invalid parameter "hccEnv", did you mean "ssh"?**

You didn't share the pipeline code however in the exception trace there is the part of the code which is producing the error: `kubernetesDeploy(hccEnv: 'd...`

If you check the documentation of the plugin which introduce `kubernetsDeploy` method, it hasn't a `hccEnv` parameter: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/kubernetes-cd/ so in order to work you have to review the call to this method.

Note also that this plugin kubernetes-cd is currently suspended as some security issues was not resolved: https://www.jenkins.io/security/advisory/2022-08-23/#SECURITY-2448